# Help with text format

Tags: text-decorations

I need to prevent a word from splitting into two lines of text. For example, the word "polinómico" splits in "po" and "linómico" when i compile the code.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

segundos para resolver un problema de $n$ variables, decimos que es resoluble en tiempo  polinómico. No así si se requirieran, por ejemplo...


\end{document}
```

I have used `\mbox`, and the word doesn't split, however, the word is awkwardly positioned far beyond the usual end of the row.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

segundos para resolver un problema de $n$ variables, decimos que es resoluble en tiempo  \mbox{polinómico}. No así si se requirieran, por ejemplo...


\end{document}
```

How can i make latex to put that word completely into the next line without using `\\`?

Note: I'm using \usepackage[spanish]{babel} and win 12-52 encoding

Comment: Your code doesn't produce the issue.

Comment: The question is interesting, but your example should be a paragraph that shows the issue.

Comment: Note that by default latex will split the word using english hyphenation rules which are unlikely to be very useful here, you may do better with `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` (if I guessed the right language:-)

Comment: What do you mean that you are using 'win 12-52' encoding? Your preamble says that the encoding of your `.tex` file is UTF8. If that is not the case, you should use a different option for `inputenc`. But I'm not sure if that is what you mean...

Comment: Also, I'm afraid that your code still doesn't reproduce the problem. When I compile (with `babel` added), the line break occurs after 'resoluble' - no hyphenation at all. Is the hyphenation wrong generally or do you just not want the word broken in this particular case? If it is general, could you state the appropriate hyphenation points for the word?

Comment: If you just want to break the line in this particular case, then you can, if necessary, add `\linebreak` before the word to encourage a line break. You should not have to do this in the vast majority of documents, so if this is more than a very, very infrequent issue, you should look for a more general diagnosis and remedy.